# R: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed: solution for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I want to run a logistic regression:

```
lrm(formula = dat$law ~ dat$argor + dat$trust.cen + dat$argor*dat$trust.cen + 
  dat$trust.abs + dat$argor*dat$trust.abs)
```

but I get this error:

> Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname == zname)) { :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Other posts have this error, but I cannot solve the problem with any of those solutions. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this and edit your question afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4132844

Comment: For starters, you could specify the formula correctly. Try `y ~ x + y + z, data = xy)`. Notice I don't use `$`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Its perfectly correct to specify vectors in a formula, without a `data` argument, as the question does. At least, that's true for `lm` - I don't know about this `lrm` function mentioned in the question...

Comment: Where does the `lrm` function come from?

Comment: @Spacedman It's from the `rms` package, I assume: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/rms/html/lrm.html

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when you use `$` in the formula. Strangely it's an issue that affects `lrm` but not `lm`. The solution is to not use `$` as per Roman in the comments. Fortunately you can work around this by referring the dataset law in the data term:

```
lrm(formula = law ~ argor + trust.cen + argor*trust.cen + trust.abs + argor*trust.abs, data = law)
```